# Sleep button not following dconf settings -- Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, suspend, hibernate, function-keys

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on my Asus ROG GL752VW, and I want my sleep button to hibernate my computer.  This computer has always been difficult for Ubuntu and Fedora.

First, I enabled hibernate and tested it through `sudo pm-hibernate`.  It worked.

Then, I attempted to make the sleep button <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> hibernate the computer.  To accomplish this, I went in to dconf-settings and went to `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power` and changed the settings for both the suspend and the sleep button to `hibernate`.  When I saved the settings then restarted the computer (which I do not think was necessary, but I did just to be safe), I double-checked that the setting was still `hibernate` using `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-suspend` and the equivalent for sleep.  After confirming, I pressed the sleep button.  The computer suspended instead of hibernating.  I then changed the value to `nothing` and restarted, and the button still suspended the computer.

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu.  I am currently using the following boot options, some of which are required to boot the computer and enable function keys (e.g. airplane mode).  I am not sure what they all do, but they seem to help:

```
nouveau.modeset=0  tpm_tis.interrupts=0 acpi_osi=! acpi_backlight=native i915.preliminary_hw_support=1
```

Any suggestions?  All the discussions I've read involve changing the values in `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power` to change the behavior of the buttons.

Comment: Would you be happy with just having a Hibernate option in the Power Menu? There's a guide on The Ubuntu Handbook for how to get this working: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/05/add-hibernate-option-ubuntu-18-04/ - Might be easier than trying to get a specific key to start Hibernation

Comment: @pHeLiOn Thank you for the suggestion, but I personally really like hotkeys.  I want a hotkey for everything I regularly do.  I actually found a way to hotkey it by making a script that hibernates and hotkeying that, but I would still like to have the sleep hotkey do it so it is consistent with my Windows dual boot (which uses the sleep button to hibernate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
    $ sudo nano /etc/acpi/events/power
```

Then add the following lines:

```
    event=button/suspend
    action=/sbin/hibernate
```

The action may not work for all users, depending on whether /sbin/hibernate works on its own.  You may need to replace it with another hibernate command like `pm-hibernate`.